# Adding custom webpart in sitepages

Tags: web-part

I created SharePoint 2013 Project. I added visual web part in project. I used asmx service in visual webpart. Then I deployed the project. I created a new page. I want to add the webpart in page. But i like get error:

[image]

How can I solve this problem? I stopped User Profile Service and Sync Service, then I started again.

Comment: There seems to be a null object in your code. Try debugging your solution or check the ULS logs for the exact error

Comment: Somewhere some object is being returned null value. Means some or the other object is not getting initialized. Try debugging the solution.